# Making a skin suit from scratch

Tags: internal-consistency, humans, clothing

A theme I see in a lot of twisted horror movies is the idea of wearing somebody’s skin and while this is sick and twisted, I am also sick and twisted, so I went to the drawing board with the hope of designing a skin suit. But I am not an engineer, which made this a problem. So after not finding a good solution after a couple minutes, I quit. Now I ask, could you make, from ''scratch'', a skin suit that is realistic enough to fool, even the police?

Let's make a few assumptions here on what I need and can do (hypothetically speaking of course):

1. The suit must be made from human skin, though the number of humans and what areas of skin does not matter.
2. The suit must be hyper realistic, to the point where I can even fly international without worry.
3. I must be able to walk around, speak and eat while wearing the suit
4. The suit must last for at least a few years, to hide the bodies and destroy the evidence.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about in what circumstances you need to fool someone, even the police.

Comment: Do you want to fool first look or go to something in the likes of Face/Off?

Comment: a suit as in a mask?  or just using human skin like leather?

Comment: Did you see the Mythbusters where they impersonate each other?

Comment: You are not clear that you mean it to take on the appearance of the person worn. This would be easier to read if that was stated up front.

Comment: *"Now I ask, could you make, from ''scratch'', a skin suit that is realistic enough to fool, even the police?"* Only by magic.

Comment: Consider editing it to have a different context. This is one of the quirks of SE type sites; you can get the answers you need no matter how off-topic your intent for them is if you give them an on-topic context. The information will still help those building fictional worlds as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No, just no.

If your skin suit is intended to make you look like someone else, the answer is definitely "No" unless you're willing to undergo radical plastic surgery to change your skeleton and muscles to match the identity of the person you want o impersonate.

Points 1, and 3 are fairly easy to manage if you're sociopathic enough to even want a suit like this.  Humanity has a long history of preserving animal skins and presumably, this knowledge could be extended to human skins too.

Point 2 isn't possible.  To travel internationally, you must pass through multiple examinations at 3 feet or less with another human being who is well trained in identifying impersonators.  Your skin suit would need to be a full face covering that mates with all the facial muscles and skin of your face.  Making the edges around the eyes and mouth match up and move normally would be very tricky.

Humans identify each other just as much on facial geometry as on skin color.  Many modern facial identification systems are based on this idea.  Millimeter differences in geometry are enough to indicate someone's identity.

Point 4 won't work.  Tanned leathers can last for centuries but no one would ever mistake tanned leather for fresh skin.  Ever.  Perhaps there's a funky preservation process that would keep the human skin in one piece but I don't know how that would be done.

Comment: To whoever finds this question, if you wouldn't mind, could you drop a note explaining how you found it?

Answer (score -4):

I don't see how this, even remotely, qualifies as worldbuilding. Anyways. Your question seems to be a question about leather. I'm not an expert, but I've never seen thin leather behave close to what human skin does. I guess you'd have to remove all of your hair and then glue it on. What would happen to all of your sweat, IDK. Of course, your nails, ears, and orifices would be a real problem. Take eye-lids, for example. Yeah, tough to replicate them. (Ears are a bit easier, you'd just cut yours off, and replace with plastic ones, or less extremely, just use make-up around the mask's ear holes to hide the edge between the leather and your ear.) Lips? Forget it. Could you fool the police? At a distance of 300 yards for 0.5 seconds? Sure. Across the table in an interrogation room? Not so much. I wrote about leather, above, but you probably know that silicone is much much much more commonly used in movies. There is a reason for this. The same issues would surround it. The real problem would be your face. (And your male genitals, as applicable.) Since your skin is constantly shedding, the glue you used would have a very limited lifetime before it began to fail, and your "skin" no longer moved the way real skin would. --You got more specific. Good, I guess. So, how are you going to find a person which is an exact match for you except just a half size bigger? Ridiculous. Making it out of pieces? More ridiculous, absurd or delusional more like. I should also mention, that your sweat will build up under the leather and in like half a day, you'd be a smell-a-thon (I don't know if antimicrobials would work, I can't envision how you'd dose yourself effectively with them.) But lets say you're ok looking like a burn victim who has been thrown through several windows (and has the scars to prove it), who has long hair, a beard, and wears dark glasses. As long as you smell as bad as you probably will, I don't think many people would pay enough attention to you to notice your fake skin.

Comment: If you believe question is off topic, you should flag it or (when you can) vote to close, not answer it. Downvote is not from me, but I guess this might be a reason for it.

Comment: What @Mołot said. Consider also making your answers less narrative-based (flowing from beginning to end with transitions in a big text wall) and more informational (a few bullets, headers, categories to group the information, etc.)